# How do you reference files stored on a mobile device?

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

When building an app (in my case for android) how would you reference and display music files that are stored on the device with Corona. I have searched http://developer.coronalabs.com/reference and I can not find it but I'm not saying its not their.

So this is view one which will be used for "songs"

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

function scene:createScene( event )
  local group = self.view

  local bg = display.newRect( 0, 0, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
  bg:setFillColor( 255 )    -- white

  local title = display.newRetinaText( "First View", 0, 0, native.systemFont, 32 )
  title:setTextColor( 0 )   -- black
  title:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
  title.x = display.contentWidth * 0.5
  title.y = 125

  local summary = display.newRetinaText( "Loaded by the first tab 'onPress' listener\n— specified in the 'tabButtons' table.", 0, 0, 292, 292, native.systemFont, 14 )
  summary:setTextColor( 0 ) -- black
  summary:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
  summary.x = display.contentWidth * 0.5 + 10
  summary.y = title.y + 215

  local sliderListener = function( event )
  local sliderObj = event.target

function buildGUI()
  print( "New value is: " .. event.target.value )
end


group:insert( bg )
group:insert( title )
group:insert( summary )
```

who wrote this on mystery account?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

Corona can only access files on its own sandbox or download stuff over http.